# How to implement IPostBackEventHandler interface into ListView?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview

I'm struggling to make `ListView` rows selectable by clicking anywhere in the row instead of using designated `Button` with `CommandName="Select"`. Here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="FileList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanging="FileList_SelectedIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FileList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnItemDataBound="FileList_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
    ...
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
        ....
            <td>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Then I have this in my `CodeBehind`:

```
protected void FileList_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ((HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("tr1")).Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(FileList, "Select$" + e.Item.DataItemIndex, true);
}
```

This successfully assigns `OnClick` attribute to my rows - as far as I can see some JavaScript is executed upon clicking plus the `Button` control I use to select the row stops working.

I used `Label` controls to intercept `Request["__EVENTTARGET"]` and `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` that the page sends upon clicking on the row, that's what I got:

```
Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$LocalMainContent$FileList";
Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "Select$3"; // i.e. "Select$" + row_number
```

Seems legit, huh.

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746166/2983632) that handles PostBack for ListView:

```
public class ListViewEvent : ListView, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        if (!eventArgument.Contains("$"))
            return;
        string[] splitEventArgument = eventArgument.Split('$');
        switch (splitEventArgument[0])
        {
            case "Select":
                SelectItem(Convert.ToInt32(splitEventArgument[1]));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now how do I implement this for my ListView? Thank you.**

Comment: your listview should register for `ListViewEvent` using delegate

Comment: How do I do this? Sorry for noobish question...

Comment: Read [this](http://www.cstruter.com/blog/248) and [this](http://aspalliance.com/345_The_Basics_of_Creating_Server_Controls.5)